# Multiple dyadic operators in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just found out, that I can not chain ["less than"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than) operators in JavaScript. I wonder if anyone know why?

Example:

```js
console.log ("should be false but is", (0 < 3 < 2)) // true
```

I can't find any documentation that says that, this expression will short-circuit after the first comparison (`0 < 3`). So why is the last comparison not made?

I have tested the expression in nodejs 16 (V8) and Firefox 111 (SpiderMonkey).

Comment: What short-circuiting do you expect here? It's parsed as `(0 < 3) < 2`, so `true < 2`, thn `1 < 2` and it's `true` - why do you expect `false` here? There is no operator chaining like in python.

Comment: It's not shortcircuiting, `0 < 3` results `true` that is evaluated to `1`, and that is compared to `2`.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. I expected `3 < 2` but got `1 < 2`.

Comment: Python is really the odd-one-out in this respect. Most programming languages either don't allow this syntax, or first evaluate `0 < 3` to a boolean and then evaluate `(boolean) < 2`, which (after coercion of the boolean to an integer) will result in true, no matter what the boolean result was.

Comment: I'll accept any of the comments as answer - if you want the points :)